# MySQLi add/edit not working nor showing errors

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to MySQLi, I did no parts of MySQL and php but not loads and I am trying to learn properly but with MySQLi as MySQL is now deprecated.. My problem is that when I add some details it redirects me to the page I want like it's supposed to when details are added but it doesn't actually insert any information into the DB, I have tried looking at phpMyAdmin and it isn't working.. Also when I click to edit a file it gives me this error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in ....

Here is the file:

```
    <?php
     include("includes/connecti.php");

      function renderForm($title = '', $poster ='', $date = '', $story = '', $error = '', $id = '')
    { ?>
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
            <html>
             <head>  
          <title>
              <?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?>
              </title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
              </head>
          <body>
        <h1><?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?></h1>
         <?php if ($error != '') {
         echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
                                            . "</div>";
                } ?>


            <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
            <?php if ($id != '') { ?>
           <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
           <p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>
          <?php } ?>
          <strong>Title: *</strong> <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"/><br/>
        <strong>Poster: *</strong> <input type="text" name="poster" value="<?php echo $poster; ?>"/>
         <strong>Date: *</strong> <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"/>
         <strong>Story: *</strong> <input type="text" name="story" value="<?php echo $story; ?>"/>
        <p>* required</p>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
       </div>
       </form>
       </body>
      </html>

    <?php }



    /*

       EDIT RECORD

    */
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
    {

   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
                    if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
                    {
                   $id = $_POST['id'];
                   $title = htmlentities($_POST['title'], ENT_QUOTES);
                 $poster = htmlentities($_POST['poster'], ENT_QUOTES);
               $date = htmlentities($_POST['date'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $story = htmlentities($_POST['story'], ENT_QUOTES);

            if ($title == '' || $poster == '' || $date == '' || $story == '')
               {
          $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
           renderForm($title, $poster, $date, $story, $error, $id);
           }
                else
            {

         if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE news SET title = ?, poster = ?, date = ?, story = ? WHERE id=?"))
                     {
               $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $title, $poster, $date, $story, $id);
              $stmt->execute();
               $stmt->close();
                      }
              else
                    {
              echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
                           }

                                    header("Location: view.php");
                            }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                            echo "Error!";
                    }
            }
        else
            {

                    if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
                    {

                            $id = $_GET['id'];


                            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=?"))
                            {
                                    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                                    $stmt->execute();

                                    $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $poster, $date, $story);
                                    $stmt->fetch();

                                    renderForm($title, $poster, $date, $story, NULL, $id);

                                    $stmt->close();
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                    echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
                            }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                            header("Location: view.php");
                    }
            }
    }



    /*

       NEW RECORD

    */
    // if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
    else
    {
            // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
            if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                    // get the form data
                          $title = htmlentities($_POST['title'], ENT_QUOTES);
                $poster = htmlentities($_POST['poster'], ENT_QUOTES);
                  $date = htmlentities($_POST['date'], ENT_QUOTES);
                     $story = htmlentities($_POST['story'], ENT_QUOTES);

                    if ($title == '' || $poster == '' || $date == '' || $story == '')
                    {

                            $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                            renderForm($title, $poster, $date, $story, $error);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT news (title, poster, date, story) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
                            {
                                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $title, $poster, $date, $story);
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $stmt->close();
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
                            }

                            header("Location: view.php");
                    }

            }

            else
            {
                    renderForm();
            }
    }

    $mysqli->close();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is one of your columns a LONGBLOB or LONGTEXT?

PHP tries to allocate enough memory to hold the maximum size of that column (4,294,967,296 bytes). See here (note the last post on the page):

[http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51386](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51386)

If that's the case, changing the column to a MEDIUMTEXT or MEDIUMBLOB, or something smaller if you can get away with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I fixed that error, now I still have the problem of the information not being updated or inserted when I use the above script..?